# What are differences between create database and create schema in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, schema

I only found out the differences between create database and create schema in MySQL. Unfortunately, I don't use MySQL for my work. So I want to ask the differences in SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, a schema is just a more granular grouping of objects that belong under a single database (so in relational terms, a database can be one-to-many to schemas).

Schemas allow more flexibility in grouping objects by relevancy and controlling access better from a security standpoint.

For example, a manufacturing company may have a database to track the items they produce, the sales of those products, and their customers they sell to. A single database could encompass all of that.

But one may use schemas to divide all of the sales related tables, `SalesOrders`, `SalesLines`, `Shipping`, etc, in the `Sales` schema. Another schema called `Production` can be used to track `Inventory`, `QuantityOnHand`, `ProductionOrders`, `ProductionLines` etc. Another schema called `Customers` can be used to store customer specific data such as the `Customers` themselves, the `CustomerAddresses`, etc.

And each of these schemas can be locked down with various security access so only certain users can access each schema or a mix of different schemas. For example, you may not want to expose sensitive `Customer` information or `Sales` data to people who need access to the `Production` data. But there may be managers or certain people who should be able to see both `Sales` and `Production` data. Schemas make it possible to divide permissions up accordingly to support those use cases.